# Control Raspberry Pi using localhost website

Tags: html, .net, tcp, raspberry-pi

I was looking into building a system that, upon pressing a button on a webpage, sends some type of signal to a raspberry pi, e.g. I press button1 on my website, and that initiates operation1 on my raspberry pi, for context, my website will probably be built using the laravel framework, the pi side will probably be using a .Net App that acts upon selections made using my website, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction as to what to do, where I should look etc.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you can do 2 things, wich is as follows.

###### First solution (Wich follows your requirements)

I would create a SignalR server that runs on the rasperry pi, SignalR is a way to develop realtime applications, wich have access to multiple forms of transport methods. Then connect your website to this SignalR server and trigger all of the "commands".

###### The second options

Create a python script wich acts as the webserver and the functions to trigger certain actions to toggle lights or whatever your're trying to do. This is the simplest and easiest solution to program.